# Publishing a web service with out creating an Interface

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS to create a web service and publish it.
What I wanted to know is; Is it possible to publish an webservice with out creating an Interface.
Meaning, right now I create an interface

End point interface class:

```
package com.ad.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface PowerCalculator
{
    @WebMethod Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power);
}
```

Then I create a interface implementor class:

```
package com.ad.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.ad.ws.PowerCalculator")
public class PowerCalculatorImpl implements PowerCalculator
{

    @Override
    public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)
    {
        return Math.pow(base, power);
    }

}
```

After this I publish using something like this:

```
package com.ad.endpoint;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import com.ad.ws.PowerCalculatorImpl;

public class PowerCalculatorPublisher
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting publish of the PowerCalculator service...");
        Endpoint.publish("http://myhostname.ad.com:8585/ayusman/PowCalc", new PowerCalculatorImpl());
    }

}
```

What I wanted to know is, can I combine both the interface and the implemntor into one; something like:

```
package com.ad.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.ad.ws.PowerCalculatorImpl")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class PowerCalculatorImpl
{

    @WebMethod public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)
    {
        return Math.pow(base, power);
    }

}
```

When I do this and start the publisher I get the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: The web service defined by the class com.ad.ws.PowerCalculatorImpl does not contain any valid WebMethods.
```

Is creating an service interface absolutely essential in creating a web service?

```
=========================================================================================
```

Update1:

I had missed the public keyword in the method signature:

```
@WebMethod public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)
```

Also after @kingAm suggestion I removed the endpointInterface so the class looks like:

```
package com.ad.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class PowerCalculatorImpl
{

    @WebMethod public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)
    {
        return Math.pow(base, power);
    }

}
```

My simple client class looks like:

```
package com.ad.client;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import com.ad.ws.PowerCalculatorImpl;

public class PowerCalculatorImplClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://myhostname.ad.com:8585/ayusman/PowCalc?wsdl");

        QName qname = new QName("http://ws.ad.com/", "PowerCalculatorService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        PowerCalculatorImpl powerCalculatorImpl = service.getPort(PowerCalculatorImpl.class);

        System.out.println(powerCalculatorImpl.raisedToThePower(2, 5));

    }
}
```

Here are the exceptions I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.ad.ws.powerCalculatorImpl is not an interface
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

It seems that the jax-ws expects an interface here or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Is creating an service interface absolutely essential in creating a web service?
```

No, it's not necessary.

```
What I wanted to know is, can I combine both the interface and the implemntor into one
```

Yes,you can. Just remove endpointInterface declaration in Webservice annotation at your implementation class.

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.ad.ws.PowerCalculatorImpl")
```

So your implementation class will be,

```
package com.ad.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService()
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class PowerCalculatorImpl
{

    @WebMethod public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)
    {
        return Math.pow(base, power);
    }

}
```

Above code should work perfectly fine without any error.

I have tried following scenario from my end and it is working perfectly fine.

My implementation class,

```
package com.KingAm.HelloWorld;

 import javax.jws.WebMethod;
  import javax.jws.WebResult;
  import javax.jws.WebService;
 import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;
 import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use=Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle= ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
    public class helloWorldImpl{

@WebMethod(action="hello",operationName="helloWorld")
@WebResult(name="response1")
public String tMethod(String a, String b, String c)
{
    if(!c.equals(null))
    return "hello "+a+b+c;
    else
        return "okok";
}

//@Override
@WebMethod(action="hello2",operationName="helloWorld2")
@WebResult(name="response2")
public String tMethod2(String a, String b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

  }
```

and My publisher class is,

```
package com.KingAm.HelloWorld;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
//import helloWorldImpl;

public class helloWorldPublisher {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/ws/helloWorld", new helloWorldImpl());
           System.out.println("Hello World Server is published!");

    }

}
```

Please check your code once, you must be missing something.

Comment: yes you are right. I had left out the "public" key word in my method signature "@WebMethod public Double raisedToThePower(Double base, Double power)". However after making the changes; when I tried to use a simple client; it still causes problem. Please see my OP edit.

Comment: Sir, put @Webservice() before your class. Or JAX WS framework won't be able to identify your implementation class as service endpoint.

Comment: if you look at it; the exception says "com.ad.ws.powerCalculatorImpl is not an interface"

Comment: I have edited my answer with an implementation which i have tried on my pc as per your issue and it is working fine.

Comment: Are you gettng this exception while executing your client code or while publishing your powercalculator server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48355/discussion-between-kingam-and-ayusman)

Comment: funny thing is when I tried the test over SOAPUI tool. and fired a test request it worked fine.